# Multiple StreamingRecognizeRequest

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I'm trying to setup a **StreamingRecognize**, with multiple request's. Is it possible ?

The point is that i want to send audio stream from the mic with a **unknown** time, so i think that i must implement multiple requests. (Considering that a request session has a max_time = 65 seconds).

Anyone can help me with this ?

Thank's alot ;)

Google sample code:

```
static async Task<object> StreamingMicRecognizeAsync(int seconds)
{
if (NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.DeviceCount < 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("No microphone!");
    return -1;
}
var speech = SpeechClient.Create();
var streamingCall = speech.StreamingRecognize();
// Write the initial request with the config.
await streamingCall.WriteAsync(
    new StreamingRecognizeRequest()
    {
        StreamingConfig = new StreamingRecognitionConfig()
        {
            Config = new RecognitionConfig()
            {
                Encoding =
                RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
                SampleRateHertz = 16000,
                LanguageCode = "en",
            },
            InterimResults = true,
        }
    });
// Print responses as they arrive.
Task printResponses = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (await streamingCall.ResponseStream.MoveNext(
        default(CancellationToken)))
    {
        foreach (var result in streamingCall.ResponseStream
            .Current.Results)
        {
            foreach (var alternative in result.Alternatives)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(alternative.Transcript);
            }
        }
    }
});
// Read from the microphone and stream to API.
object writeLock = new object();
bool writeMore = true;
var waveIn = new NAudio.Wave.WaveInEvent();
waveIn.DeviceNumber = 0;
waveIn.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(16000, 1);
waveIn.DataAvailable +=
    (object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs args) =>
    {
        lock (writeLock)
        {
            if (!writeMore) return;
            streamingCall.WriteAsync(
                new StreamingRecognizeRequest()
                {
                    AudioContent = Google.Protobuf.ByteString
                        .CopyFrom(args.Buffer, 0, args.BytesRecorded)
                }).Wait();
        }
    };
waveIn.StartRecording();
Console.WriteLine("Speak now.");
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));
// Stop recording and shut down.
waveIn.StopRecording();
lock (writeLock) writeMore = false;
await streamingCall.WriteCompleteAsync();
await printResponses;
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cloud Speech-to-Text audio length limit for each streaming request is around 1 minute [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas). You can either use asynchronous speech recognition [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize) for audio files up to 180 minutes or renew the streaming request before it reaches to the time limit for streaming speech recognition [[3]](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize#performing_streaming_speech_recognition_on_an_audio_stream).

Here is a Python example how to renew streaming request and stream audio more than 1 minute [[4]](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/speech-continuous/speech/cloud-client/transcribe_streaming_indefinite.py).

Comment: I really apreciate your help! I tried to setup an asynchronous recognition before, but it has a delay that can't work so well for this type of solution. I'm not very familiar with Python, but in these example, when the request generating an exception, the 'resume' variable is setted to true and after a new stream requesting comes up ? 

I found this example, that works pretty well. This is exactly what i want to do, but in c#. [Google Speech Demo](https://www.google.com/intl/pt/chrome/demos/speech.html)

Comment: You can have a look to the Google Cloud Speech API Samples for C# [(1)](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/api). You need to make the customization to the Recognize.cs file[(2)](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/api/Recognize) for your desired streaming speech recognition.